# flutter: parameter format not correct

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, visual-studio-code

I am new to Flutter and today I've been stuck to one problem. I cannot debug my app because it says parameter format not correct

```
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Several variant outputs are configured to use the same file name "resources-debug.ap_", filters : MAIN:MAIN
```

Here's my flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)
 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I've looked for answers everywhere and they didn't work for my case. Most of the solutions are suggesting to change environment path. This is my path: C:\src\flutter\bin
note: I'm using VSCode

Please help.. thank you!

Comment: Not sure exactly how to fix it but follow this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57311) to see if you'll find a way around it.

Comment: @AkoraIng.DKB Thank you for responding! :)

Comment: i have a same issues here

Answer (score 3):

This error occurred because of the app level **Gradle.file minSdkVersion** property is less than  20 or the **targetSdkVersion** property is less than 30.

It may work for you. In my case, it works perfectly.

`minSdkVersion` : 20

`targetSdkVersion` : 30

Answer (score 2):

As I observe your Flutter Doctor, it's already defined that **Android toolchain** and the **Android Studio**android studio is not configured. So. follow the below steps.
For resolve **Android toolchain** run the **"flutter doctor --android-licenses"**. And for "Android Studio" resolve please **goto Android Studio -> Files -> Settings -> Plugins -> install the Flutter**. While installing flutter its also asked for install dart click ok and after installation, it will ask to restart the Android Studio. After restart goes to Flutter terminal and runs Flutter Doctor, Now you have resolved the above issue. The last issue is just ignored because it's just showing that no devices are connected.

And you can run the Flutter in Android Studio in Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

run these commands in your project folder in the order shown below,

1. `flutter channel stable`
2. `flutter upgrade --force`
3. `flutter pub cache repair`
4. `flutter clean`

Now try to run your project.

Comment: Please put the the code that is meant to be executed in the terminal into a code block.

Comment: i donnt get it man

Comment: like step by step? channel stable and then upgrade? like tthat?

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not affect the build process, personally I faced it every time it occurs when you use previous flutter SDK version and sometimes relate with windows pc but it's not a big deal at all I have created about 7 apps under the same warning "Parameter format not correct -" and they just work fine.

[image]

The above problem relate with android studio (toolchain cmd) and license, you have to install android toolchain command line in android SDK on android studio.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is due to a name in the path where you have your project, remember that the folders should not have spaces, or some unusual character, try to check that you do not have accents or spaces.